# Impact of using egg yolks vs whites in a spaghetti dish?

Tags: eggs, pasta, egg-whites

I'm making a dish that calls for several egg yolks and 1 full egg (all scrambled together) to be poured over hot spaghetti and cooked salt pork (to cook the egg), and I'm wondering how much of a difference using yolks vs using whites makes.

If I could use the entire egg, I would be able to use less total eggs; but if this will have a serious impact on the dish, then I don't want to mess it up.

Thoughts?

Comment: What is this dish? I've never heard of such a thing...

Comment: Its my family's version of Spaghetti Carbonara. I understand that there are many different versions and makes of this dish, but my father brought this one back from Italy in the 60's, so i'd like to think its the most authentic :P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Yolk and White are very different and I would expect to see a significant difference in result.

That isn't to say it will be bad, just different.

The Yolk is the source of fat.  It is going to impart flavor to the dish and provide a creamier texture.

The White is mostly protein and so will set more, have more of a texture impact.

If it called for several whole eggs and you wanted to take a Yolk or two out for less fat, that would have less of a variance, but switching several Yolks to several Whites should definitely alter the results.

**Extra info:**
Here is some nutritional information of a Large Whole/White/Yolk.
http://www.incredibleegg.org/health-and-nutrition/egg-nutrients/nutrient-chart

You will see they both carry protein however the Yolk has almost twice as much fat as protein while the White has less than 2% of fat as it does protein.

This makes their behaviors very different.

Answer (score 0):

Whites behave differently (coagulate differently, for instance). If it is a dish you'd likely make more often - why not try both variants and see how you like it? Everyone's got their own preferred style, perhaps it fits you?

Answer (score 0):

Tried this both ways. Yolks only is the way to make this wonderful dish. A little bit of white won’t matter if you don’t separate them completely. After frying the pancetta almost all the way add minced garlic and a little white wine, let wine cook off for a few minutes. Delish.